# How to use Google Analytics tracking code with node-express app?

Tags: node.js, express, google-analytics

I am making a click tracking application in nodejs. I am using ejs as template engine with express. I want to add google analytics tracking code to my app. I am able to add it on the pages where I am rendering a view. But as I already said its a tracking application, when someone clicks on link generated by this application, it gets redirected to it a clients specific landing page.

So I am not able to add a GA tracking code to the URL where any view is not rendering but in response it is get redirecting.

I am new to all this guys, please I need your help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have actual page views to track you can use Google Analytics Events. These allow you to track almost anything. You could add javascript on the pages to send an event on link clicks just using the regular Google api:

```
function handleClick(event) {
  ga('send', 'event', {
     eventCategory: 'Outbound Link',
     eventAction: 'click',
     eventLabel: event.target.href,
  });
}
```

or if you prefer you can send the events from the server side with something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-analytics#event-tracking

This would allow you to send events directly from Node.

Events are very flexible (you can define any categories and actions you need) and they show up in realtime views and stats in Google Analytics.

More here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I want to clear one thing about the links I want to track will not be on my application itself. The links generated by my application will be used in emails or banner ads. Will it work in this case?

Comment: @VyankateshCharakpalli so long as you have access to javascript somewhere in the pipeline you should be able to make it work. For example links from email will hit your server -- your server will send the event to google. It shouldn't be too hard, just like writing logs.